# Simple scanf does not set variable value

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote this simple and short code in C and can't get it to work properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char var1[2];
    int var2, var3;
    unsigned char var4;

    scanf("%s %d %d %d", var1, &var2, &var3, &var4);
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n", var1, var2, var3, var4);

    return 0;
}
```

If I input `P2 45 45 200`, I get `P2 45 0 200`, I can't understand why `var3` does not receive its assigned value.

Input: `P2 45 45 200`

Expected output: `P2 45 45 200`

Output: `P2 45 0 200`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `var4`, you declare it as `unsigned char`, but read it using a `%d` format specifier, which invokes undefined behavior.

I would recommend using `%hhu` as the format specifier for that field, if your compiler supports it. Or you could declare `var4` as an `int`, and
then assign it to an `unsigned char` variable after the `scanf()` call.